# Agregar datos a tabla HTML dinámica desde función success de jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Estoy enviando un dato via jQuery a un controlador MVC de la siguiente manera:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#submit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var dui = $("#inputText1").val('');
                var lastname = $("#inputText2").val('');
                var name = $("#inputText3").val('');
                var country = $("#inputText4").val('');
                var DUI = $("#inputText5").val('');
                var ISSS = $("#inputText6").val('');

                var datos = {
                    id : $("#inputText1").val()
                };

 $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/PruebaHTML",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:  datos,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.respuesta == "OK")
                            alert("Muy Bien");

                        $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td for="dui">' + dui + '</td><td for="lastname">' + lastname + '</td><td for="name">' + name + '</td><td>' + country + '</td><td for="DUI">' + DUI + '</td><td for="ISSS">' + ISSS + '</td><td><a href="#" id="select">Modificar</a></td></tr>');
                        $("#inputText1").val('');
                        $("#inputText2").val('');
                        $("#inputText3").val('');
                        $("#inputText4").val('');
                        $("#inputText5").val('');
                        $("#inputText6").val('');
                        $('#inputText1').focus();

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status) {
                        alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
                    },

                    // código a ejecutar sin importar si la petición falló o no
                    complete: function (xhr, status) {
                        alert('Petición realizada');
                    }
                });
```

como pueden ver en caso la funcion success reciba un "OK" entonces quiero agregar a una tabla HTML los registros que almacene en variables javacript

```
                    var dui = $("#inputText1").val('');
                    var lastname = $("#inputText2").val('');
                    var name = $("#inputText3").val('');
                    var country = $("#inputText4").val('');
                    var DUI = $("#inputText5").val('');
                    var ISSS = $("#inputText6").val('');
```

y esta es la tabla que utilizo

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="myTable" style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Nivel</th>
                    <th>DUI</th>
                    <th>ISSS</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

pero no me carga los datos, yo no quiero hacer ninguna llamada a la base de datos para cargar la tabla  simplemente si el controlador a traves de jQuery logo ingresar los datos pues agrego los valores de los inputs en la tabla HTML...nada de base de datos para poblar la tabla, pueden ayudarme por favor, aqui les dejo la imagen de lo que la tabla me muestra al ejecutar la funcion success

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

imagen de lo que me aparecece en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: dejame ver si entiendo, dices que cuendo el usuario le de click al formulario, esa info se va a la bd y pues tu quieres que sin que la consulte de nuevo, se muestren los valores en tu tabla?

Comment: Comprobá que estés recibiendo datos correctamente desde "/Home/PruebaHTML"
En todo caso, para probar y descartar podes ir asignando valores "a mano" en el AJAX si es que entra al success

Comment: no, el usuario enviara solo un dato de los seis que existen en el formulario, en caso la llamada a $.ajax regrese "OK" entonces los demás inputs se agregan a la tabla HTML, luego los ingresara como un list<entidad> pero de momento solo necesito mostrarlos en la tabla HTML

Comment: um ok, bueno puedes hacer un 'console.log' de alguno de los datos y mostrarnos lo que sale en la consola?

Comment: le puse console.log(dui); antes de llamar a $.ajax y no me muestra nada en la consola, dejo la imagen en la pregunta

Comment: no entiendo muy bien lo que estas haciendo, recuerda que hay que tratar de explicarlo de la mejor manera posible.  si dices que ningun dato viene de la bd, entonces creo que cuendo estas asignando los valores a las variables antes de el ajax, estas enviando nada en realidad , recuerda que la funcion .val() es getter y setter al mismo timepo, si pones .val('') estas asignando un valor vacio al campo y pues supongo que eso regresa un objeto que es lo que te aparece, intenta quitar las comillas.

Comment: Estás borrando los datos antes de enviarlos con AJAX

Comment: Explico: solo estoy mandando un valor de los seis que existen en el formulario, no tengo necesidad de en enviarlos todos, ahora cuando el controller recibe el dato hace las validaciones necesarias y si en la funcion success recibo "OK" entonces los demas inputs, los cuales no mande via $.ajax los ingreso en la tabla HTML, en ningún momento mando todos los datos del formulario en la llamada $.ajax, solamente envió uno y si todo sale bien cargo la información de los campos en la tabla HTML, nunca los envio vía $.ajax y no recupero ninguna información de la base de datos.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro borro los datos luego de haber ingresado los datos en la tabla

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro pero aqui lo que hago es recuperar el valor del input  var dui = $("#inputText1").val(''); y luego, despues del append a la tabla HTML hago esto para limpiar cada input  $("#inputText1").val('');  puedes ayudarme y decirme en que me equivoco por favor

Comment: @PabloTobar Los estás borrando al principio de tu código, justo antes de hacer la llamada AJAX, por lo que `datos` siempre irá vacío. Mira la respuesta que te he puesto donde lo explico mejor (o eso espero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás borrando los datos antes de enviarlos con AJAX:

```
            var dui = $("#inputText1").val('');
            var lastname = $("#inputText2").val('');
            var name = $("#inputText3").val('');
            var country = $("#inputText4").val('');
            var DUI = $("#inputText5").val('');
            var ISSS = $("#inputText6").val('');

            var datos = {
                id : $("#inputText1").val()
            };
```

Al hacer `.val('');` lo que estás haciendo es asignarle a esos `input` el valor vacío. Y luego al hacer `id : $("#inputText1").val()`, `$("#inputText1").val()` siempre tendrá el valor "" porque es lo que le asignaste en la primera línea (al hacer `$("#inputText1").val('')`). Deberías corregir eso en tu código para que simplemente se lean los valores en lugar de sobreescribirlos:

```
            var dui = $("#inputText1").val();
            var lastname = $("#inputText2").val();
            var name = $("#inputText3").val();
            var country = $("#inputText4").val();
            var DUI = $("#inputText5").val();
            var ISSS = $("#inputText6").val();
```

Corrige eso, y comprueba si es lo que te causa el error.

Comment: Exacto, gracias por la paciencia.